Parse transforms on SVGUseElement
I'm trying to parse transforms on a SVGUseElement embedded in an SVGPatternElement.
Here's an illustrative case:
<svg viewBox="0 0 239 57">
  <circle cx="28.5" cy="24.5" r="17.5" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use href="#image0_7_9" transform="scale(0.00042735)"/>
    </pattern>
    <image id="image0_7_9" width="2340" height="2340" href="image.png" />
  </defs>
</svg>

This particular image is supposed to fill the frame of the circle element, so the correct scale is 0.0149 – and not 0.0004. For cases with other transforms, like translate or matrix it's the same discrepancy. My first guess was that it had to do with the tile size of the pattern element relative to either the dimensions of the SVG or the circle element, but changing tile size only seems to affect the resolution of the rendered image.

If I understand you right, you really don't want to show that image repeatedly, just to clip it to a circular form? Why don't you use a <clipPath> or hust a CSS clip-path: circle() for that task? It is much easier to handle than trying to get the <pattern> right.

I agree, but this is they way Figma embeds images in SVG – for some reason.

Believe me, it is just bullshit. Twenty years back, when CSS had no object-position, it was common to abuse patterned background images for positioning. Then someone had the bad idea to transfer that to SVG one to one, where it was never needed in the first place. Figma should be ashamed of themselves to still have that sort of code.

So, it turns out the actual scale divided by the scale in the use-element is the same as the diameter of the <circle>. Interesting ️
